# Chained selects - delegate dynamically added select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [chained selects](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained). What i need to do, is to use multiple selects added dynamically by user, but it won't work.
[Here](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained/demo.html) is a demo page with multiple chained selects

Here's a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/5qLfn/

And here's code:

```
  <form>
    <select class="mark-remote" name="mark">
      <option value="">--</option>
      <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <select class="series-remote" name="series">
      <option value="">--</option>
    </select>
    <select class="model-remote"  name="model">
      <option value="">--</option>
    </select>
    <select class="engine-remote" name="engine">
      <option value="">--</option>
    </select>

    <button id="button-remote" type="submit">Button</button>
  </form>
  <form>
    <select class="mark-remote" name="mark">
      <option value="">--</option>
      <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <select class="series-remote" name="series">
      <option value="">--</option>
    </select>
    <select class="model-remote"  name="model">
      <option value="">--</option>
    </select>
    <select class="engine-remote" name="engine">
      <option value="">--</option>
    </select>

    <button id="button-remote" type="submit">Button</button>
  </form>
  <form>
    <select class="mark-remote" name="mark">
      <option value="">--</option>
      <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <select class="series-remote" name="series">
      <option value="">--</option>
    </select>
    <select class="model-remote"  name="model">
      <option value="">--</option>
    </select>
    <select class="engine-remote" name="engine">
      <option value="">--</option>
    </select>

    <button id="button-remote" type="submit">Button</button>
  </form>

/* For multiple jquery.chained.js */
$(".series").each(function() {
    $(this).chained($(".mark", $(this).parent()));
});
$(".model").each(function() {
    $(this).chained($(".series", $(this).parent()));
});
$(".engine").each(function() {
    $(this).chained([
        $(".series", $(this).parent()),
        $(".model", $(this).parent())
    ]);
});
```

And it work's for me as a static selects. But it won't work when I try do add new level with jquery like this:

```
$("#ql_add_case_schema").on("click", function () {
    var select='\
                <div class="container">\n\
                    <div class="row clearfix">\n\
                        <div class="col-md-1 column">\n\
                            USUN\n\
                        </div>\n\
                        <div class="col-md-2 column">\n\
                            <select class="mark-remote" name="mark"><option value="">--</option><option value="bmw">BMW</option><option value="audi">Audi</option></select>\n\
                        </div>\n\
                        <div class="col-md-2 column">\n\
                            <select class="series-remote" name="series"><option value="">--</option></select>\n\
                        </div>\n\
                        <div class="col-md-2 column">\n\
                            <select class="model-remote"  name="model"><option value="">--</option></select>\n\
                        </div>\n\
                        <div class="col-md-2 column">\n\
                            <select class="engine-remote" name="engine"><option value="">--</option></select>\n\
                        </div>\n\
                    </div>\n\
                </div>\n\
                </div>';

    $('#ql_div_kodowania').append(select);
});
```

Comment: after appending dynamic elements again call that chained function inside the click functiion

Comment: I've try 
    $(".series-remote").on("click", function () {
        $(".series-remote").each(function() {
            $(this).remoteChained($(".mark-remote", $(this).parent()), "json.php");
        });
    });
but it won't work...